# Форма глагола и союз во фразе "кто и/или что поможет/помогут быть здоровым?"

Tags: союзы, глаголы, единственное-множественное-число, словоизменение

Наткнулся на вопрос вроде **"кто и что помогут быть здоровым?"** (важен только союз и форма глагола "помогут").

Возникло сомнение насчёт формы глагола, что должно быть **"кто и что *поможет* быть здоровым"**. Просто на уровне интуиции. Хотя из-за однородных подлежащих с союзом **"и"** глагол, казалось бы, действительно должен быть в форме множественного числа.

В гугле удалось найти примеры именно с **"кто и что *поможет*"**. Но никакого лингвистического анализа подобных фраз найти не получается.

И аргументировать использование глагола именно в форме единственного числа сложно. Может быть, союз **"и"** используется не совсем в обычном значении объединения, ведь "кто" и "что" - это не два конкретных субъекта, скорее, **"кто и что"** - это некая собирательная конструкция.

Или же здесь вовсе должен быть союз **"или"** вместо **"и"**? Или допустимы разные комбинации союзов и форм глагола?

Comment: Аргумент простой (я достаю свой прямой аргумент и выкладываю на всеобщее обозрение). Предложение "Врач и свежий воздух помогут быть здоровым." - корректно, вроде с этим никто не будет спорить. И далее никто не мешает нам заменить врача на кто, а свежий воздух на что: "- Врач и свежий воздух помогут быть здоровым. Извините, я не расслышал, - кто и что помогут быть здоровым?"

Comment: @user190920 в таком случае согласен полностью, но если вопрос самостоятельный, а не для уточнения, это уже похоже на другой случай, и в качестве ответа на него может быть назван вообще единственный объект, например, только "свежий воздух" или только "врач", или вообще "ничего". И поэтому же сомневаюсь, правильно ли здесь использовать союз "и".

Comment: Ну это вопрос скорее стиля. Да фраза кривовато звучит. Однозначно лучше "кто и что поможет". Но не страшно и наоборот. Сравните "Ты зачем сюда пришел" - "у меня не было другого выбора". Тоже ведь можно предъявить претензии к вопросу или ответу, но это обычное дело.